# How to ignore properties during verification with custom object in rest-assured

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, hamcrest, web-api-testing

I need to validate the entire JSON response against an expected `JsonObject` from `org.json.simple` package while ignoring some additional properties from the response

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("key1", "value1");
jsonObject.put("key2", "value2");

given().post("some/url").then().assertThat().body("result", equalTo(jsonObject, ignore="ignoreKey")) //something like this
```

The response returned from the api is like this:

```
{
    "result": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "ignoreKey": "ignoreValue"
    }
}
```

1. I do not care about the order of key/values
2. I care about both keys and values
3. I know I can get individual values using `jsonPath` but the actual JSON is quite large and complex so I would like to avoid making multiple assertions like this:

```
    response.then().assertThat().body("result.key1", equalTo(jsonObject.get("key1")));
    response.then().assertThat().body("result.key2", equalTo(jsonObject.get("key2")));
```

Note: I am using hamcrest matchers - equalTo()

Comment: I tested `body("result", equalTo(jsonObject))` and it works. So what is your problem? Do you want to compare complex and many nested-level JSON?

Comment: Result has some additional properties that I would like to ignore. And yes it is a complex, nested JSON

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a json with date fields that are generated by the application and I want to ignore them in my TEST JSON file. Have you figured it out?

Comment: @AhmedAziz You can create POJO classes of your data model and read the response into that instead of JsonObject. Then you can override the equals method of your class to ignore the date fields

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts here (from someone who used to use rest assured):

1-your clients would like an sdk yo consume your service. All industry leaders (think aws, Salesforce, etc) come with a working sdk, as it saves their clients work.

2-having an sdk saves you work, as you know teams are using a common library rather than having to debug a different implementation per team.

3-you can generate fully functional clients/models (just put in the base url) from your open api spec with a few lines in gradle: https://medium.com/codex/generating-clients-models-for-restful-services-from-openapi-specification-edf211e5d761

4-you have to integration. test your api anyways (check things like api gateway -> lambda permissions) so why not use your generated client (often with something like cucumber tests).

So in the end, I’d replace rest assured with a generated client, which will return strongly typed models.  Then you can just use regular junit (such as equals on the whole object, or asserts on a single field) to verify your responses Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes sense but it is not relevant to the project I am working on as we have no plans to offer an SDK at this moment and the application to test the API using rest-assured is already quite developed and something that cannot be discarded.